# Enunciate not can't determine output type for javax.ws.rs.core.Response

Tags: java, response, jax-rs, httpresponse, enunciate

I have a REST web service that returns a "javax.ws.rs.core.Response" entity.  When I run enunciate, it can't determine the output type, so the response in the generated wadl is left blank:

If the code look like this:

```
@GET
@Path("/webservice")
@Produces({"application/xml"})
@TypeHint(myClass.class)
javax.ws.rs.core.Response methodCall(...
```

The WADL reads:

```
    ...
    <wadl:representation mediaType="application/xml"/>
</wadl:response>
```

Rather than:

```
    ...
    <wadl:representation mediaType="application/xml" element="ns1:myClass" xmlns:ns1="http://pathTo/schema"/>
</wadl:response>
```

It here anyway to get enunciate to recognize the Response return type?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes. Use the @org.codehaus.enunciate.jaxrs.TypeHint annotation on the method to give Enunciate a hint about the output type.

Comment: I added "@TypeHint(my.class)" to my method and "import org.codehaus.enunciate.jaxrs.TypeHint;".  In my pom.xml I added the following xml, but it does not seem to change the output.  Is there more I need to do?
<dependency>
          <groupId>org.codehaus.enunciate</groupId>
          <artifactId>enunciate-core-annotations</artifactId>
          <version>1.21.1</version>
      </dependency>

Comment: So, we've got tests that prove the @TypeHint annotation is working. You can see the test module here:

https://svn.codehaus.org/enunciate/trunk/enunciate/integration-tests/jersey-storage

Comment: Turns out enunciate may have an issue when the class identified in the @TypeHint is external from the maven module it is in. (see http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/ENUNCIATE-535?focusedCommentId=260103#action_260103).  I'm going to access Ryan's answer.

Comment: how about mentioning if the type is a list of object?

Comment: @kalyan There's definitely not support for any kind of generic-y stuff in the type hints right now.